# How can I navigate up an unknown number of folders until I reach a known name

Tags: windows, batch-file, virtualenv

I am writing a batch file that lies somewhere in a folder structure alongside a .venv folder (python virtual environment)

```
KnownFolderName
|
+-- 1.0.0
|  |
|  +-- .venv
|  |
|  +-- folder
|     |
|     +-- folder
|        |
|        +-- batch.bat
|
+-- 1.0.1
   |
   +-- .venv
   |
   +-- folder
      |
      +-- batch.bat
```

I want to be able to navigate to .venv from wherever the batch file starts.

If you do this manually you can just cd .. until you reach x.y.z then cd .venv

But I can't work out how to automate that in a batch file.

findstr doesn't return a substring match which was going to be my way to get to KnownFolderName/x.y.z directly. Maybe a looping if would work?

Comment: Please share a [mcve] of your coding attempts! You know the exact location/path of `KnownFolderName`, don't you? Yes, you could do a loop with goto, going a directory level up each time, and when having reached `KnownFolderName`, returning to the previous folder which is `x.y.z`, but I think there are even easier ways. Is `KnownFolderName` a unique name within this directory tree?

Comment: Thanks. As soon as I ended my question with "maybe a looping if would work" I went off an tried it, and sure enough that works.

Answer (score 1):

Got it. Of course as soon as I post the question the answer appears!

After trying all sorts of ways to extract the string from the cwd I found that just looping backwards is the way:

```
:loop
IF EXIST .venv (
cd .venv\Scripts
) ELSE (
cd ..
goto loop
)
```

Then you can return to the original location with the standard:

```
%~dp0
```

Comment: Nice, but this relies on the fact that the current working directory is the one where the batch file resides (in the respective sub-tree); to guarantee that just put `cd /D "%~dp0."` on top...

Answer (score 0):

What about the following approach which makes use of string manipulation features:

```cmd
@echo off
set "BATCH=%~f0"
echo ABSOLUTE BATCH PATH: "%BATCH%"
set "RELATIVE=%BATCH:*\KnownFolderName\=%"
echo RELATIVE BATCH PATH: "%RELATIVE%"
set "TEST=%BATCH%|"
call set "ROOT=%%TEST:\%RELATIVE%|=%%"
echo ROOT DIRECTORY PATH: "%ROOT%"
set "VERSION=%RELATIVE:\=" & rem "%"
echo VERSION NUMBER NAME: "%VERSION%"
set "TARGET=%ROOT%\%VERSION%\.venv"
echo DESIRED FOLDER PATH: "%TARGET%"
if exist "%TARGET%\" (echo     ^(WHICH EXISTS^)) else (echo     ^(WHICH DOES NOT EXIST^))
pause
```